# Image is not uploading from public/asset to the page, giving connection error in Rails via Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, file-upload, carrierwave

I have a problem with uploading the images from local as env=production or in heroku. I have spent two days to find a solution, but I couldn't find any.

When I want to add an image locally in production mode, it's appearing in the public folder but cannot use it.

I am uploading images via 'carrierwave' gem.
I have downloaded 'figaro' and 'fog-aws' as well.
Except uploading an image for user avatar from local, everything is working perfectly.
You can check the application that I am trying to complete from here: https://young-atoll-50498.herokuapp.com/?locale=en
**you should sign up first for trying to upload image.*

Here is my AvatarUploader:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
    
  def default_url(*args)
  model.name ||= ''
  
  case 
  when ( model.name.empty? )           then ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("cat")
  when ( model.name[0].downcase < 'h') then ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("cat")
  when ( model.name[0].downcase < 'n') then ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("octahedron")
  when ( model.name[0].downcase < 'u') then ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("pyramid")
  else ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("happy_cone")
  end
 end
end
```

I have mount_uploader in my user.rb

```
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
```

Here is userController#update

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(edit_user_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

private

def edit_user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :avatar_url, :role, :avatar)
end
```

I am getting this error in production mode:

```
excon.error.response
  :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>4ADD67E52EF3DB0B</RequestId><HostId>6AELpBiQhDEsHwWU2usKMrg0kvF5ZG/XqXhNLzteahK1Ajyqk1Irru35xAetrKKbmIlMsOjGEp0=</HostId></Error>"
  :cookies       => [
  ]
  :headers       => {
    "Connection"       => "close"
    "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
    "Date"             => "Tue, 17 Nov 2020 15:06:44 GMT"
    "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
    "x-amz-id-2"       => "6AELpBiQhDEsHwWU2usKMrg0kvF5ZG/XqXhNLzteahK1Ajyqk1Irru35xAetrKKbmIlMsOjGEp0="
    "x-amz-request-id" => "4ADD67E52EF3DB0B"
  }
  :host          => "extensionschool-p4.s3.amazonaws.com"
  :local_address => "192.168.1.20"
  :local_port    => 57691
  :path          => "/uploads/user/avatar/1/ProfilePhoto.png"
  :port          => 443
  :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
  :remote_ip     => "52.217.1.188"
  :status        => 403
  :status_line   => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
):
F, [2020-11-17T16:06:45.498764 #19316] FATAL -- : [dae587c2-d7cd-41cd-b5b7-202052fcd4b1]   
F, [2020-11-17T16:06:45.498795 #19316] FATAL -- : [dae587c2-d7cd-41cd-b5b7-202052fcd4b1] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:38:in `block in update'
[dae587c2-d7cd-41cd-b5b7-202052fcd4b1] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:37:in `update'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem and would like to write down the solution for who might have the same problem in the future...

I was following instructions of the following article because my course recommended that one: https://blog.thefirehoseproject.com/posts/switching-carrierwave-to-use-s3-with-heroku-and-localhost/

*but this is quite old one!

I was getting the error about connecting to S3server. While arranging the 'Permissions, while creating a user for Amazon IAM Dashboard, you should make three first 'off' and last one 'on'. So, you can upload images.

Block all public access -> Off

- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs): Off
- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs): Off
- Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies: Off
- Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies: On

Happy coding!